# Three20 JSON problem: Can deploy to simulator but not device (extThree20JSON)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, three20

Everything builds and runs in the simulator fine ... but when I attempt to run on device I get:

> "arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1:
>   ..../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libextThree20JSON+YAJL.a:
>   No such file or directory"

I check that directory and indeed the file doesn't exist.  It does exist in the "Debug-iphoneosimulator" though (which I guess explains why it works in the simulator).

So what gives and what can I do to correct this?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. Please let us know if you solved it.

Comment: I'm also wondering if you solved this. I added the library using the included python scripts:
python ttmodule.py -p /path/myproject.xcodeproj -c Debug -c Release extThree20JSON:extThree20JSON+YAJL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed by adding the library via the python script from Three20. Do this in the command line:

`python src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p ~/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj -c Debug -c Release extThree20JSON:extThree20JSON+SBJSON`

OR

`python src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p ~/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj -c Debug -c Release extThree20JSON:extThree20JSON+YAJL`

depending on which library you need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building libextThree20JSON+YAJL.a from source, or did you just copy that .a file into your project? If the latter, the problem is probably that it is built for your computer's architecture (probably i386 or x86_64) and not ARM, what the iPhone/iPad use. To work on the device you need to either add the ARM-built version to your project, or add the library's source to your project so that it will automatically be built for the correct architecture with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from SBJSON to YAJL and for me a **Clean Build Folder** helped.